# Getting inserted (or existing) ids with executeBatch()

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am trying to insert some words to database and return newly inserted id or existing id if the word is already in the database.

I found that I can do this using `PreparedStatement` and including `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`. But `PreparedStatement` is terribly slow. I need to insert like 5000  words at once. Another way I could achieve it by running individual query in for loop:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> addWords(ArrayList<String[]> allTermsForTag) {
    ArrayList ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try{
        Statement st = connection.createStatement();
        for (String[] articleTerms: allTermsForTag) {
            for(String term: articleTerms) {
                String query = "WITH a AS (INSERT INTO tag (name) SELECT '"+term+"' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM tag WHERE name = '"+term+"') " +
                        "RETURNING id) SELECT id FROM a UNION SELECT id FROM tag WHERE name = '"+term+"'";
                rs = st.executeQuery(query);
                while (rs.next())
                {
                    int id = rs.getInt(1);
                    ids.add(id);
                    System.out.printf("id: "+id);

                }
            }
        }
        rs.close();
        st.close();
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println("SQL exception was raised while performing SELECT: "+e);
    }
    return ids;


}
```

This does what I need nicely, but this is too slow as well.

Another method that I wrote uses `executeBatch()`, however, it does not return ids:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> addWords(ArrayList<String[]> allTermsForTag){
        ResultSet rs = null;
        ArrayList ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        try{
            Statement st = connection.createStatement();
            for (String[] articleTerms: allTermsForTag) {
                for(String term: articleTerms) {
                    String query = "WITH a AS (INSERT INTO tag (name) SELECT '"+term+"' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM tag WHERE name = '"+term+"') " +
                            "RETURNING id) SELECT id FROM a UNION SELECT id FROM tag WHERE name = '"+term+"'";
                    st.addBatch(query);
                }
                st.executeBatch();
                rs = st.getGeneratedKeys();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    int id = rs.getInt(1);
                    ids.add(id);
                }
            }
            st.close();
            return ids;
        }catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.println("SQL exception was raised while performing batch INSERT: "+e.getNextException());
            System.out.println("dub");
        }
        return null;
    }
```

So the question is - how to get ids when using `executeBatch()` or if this is not possible, how to approach this problem? I need it to work as fast as possible, because there will be a lot of INSERT operations with large amount of data.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`executeBatch` can return generated keys in the latest PgJDBC versions. See [issue 195](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/195) and [pull 204](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/204). You must use [the `prepareStatement` variant that takes a `String[]` of returned column names](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])).

However... take a step back here. The solution isn't loops. The solution is almost never loops.

In this case, you should almost certainly use `COPY` via [the PgJDBC `CopyManager` API](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html) to `COPY` data into a `TEMPORARY` table. Then do an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... RETURNING ...` to insert the temp table's contents into the final table and return any generated fields. You can also do a `SELECT` to join on the temp table to return any that already exist. This is basically a [bulk upsert](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17267417/398670) or closely related bulk insert-if-not-exists.

If for some reason you can't do that, the next-best option is probably multi-valued `INSERT`s with large `VALUES` lists, but this requires some ugly dynamic SQL. Since you need existing values if the row already exists you'll probably need a writeable CTE too. So really, just use `COPY` and a query to do the table merge.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That is some advanced stuff you talking about) Not familiar with most of those, but will try to figure out. So, if I have a table with my data, I COPY it to temp table? Then do - INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... RETURNING ... form the temp table, right? And I suppose, it all should be done in transaction?

Comment: @Sermilion Yep, pretty much. You can just try a very recent jdbc driver and batch insert with generated keys otherwise. It will be quite a bit slower but probably fast enough.

Comment: Well, I ve added driver version 9.4-1201-jdbc4. It gives me the same error: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: A result was returned when none was expected.
Could you look at the code for executeBatch() and see it everything is ok. Or maybe I added wrong version of jdbc? Thank you .

Comment: @Sermilion You can't use RETTURNING directly. You have to pass the desired colunns to the createPrepared call.

Comment: preparedStatement works) But very slow. I ll try to work with COPY. I accept your answer. Thank you a lot)

Answer (score 5):

```
Set set = new HashSet();
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement("delete  from myTable where... ", 
        Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        ps.setInt(1,200);
        ps.setInt(2,262);
        ps.setString(3, "108gf99");
        ps.addBatch();
        ps.setInt(1,200);
        ps.setInt(2,250);
        ps.setString(3, "hgfha");
        ps.addBatch();
        ps.executeBatch();
        ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
        while (rs.next()){

            set.addAll(Collections.singleton(rs.getLong(1)));
        }

        System.out.println(set);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)